# .NET Core 3.1 - Ajax OnGet and return objects using NEW System.Text.Json

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0, system.text.json, .net-core-3.1

I stumbled across this issue today for the first time when trying to return an array of objects from a LINQ query that contains a foreign key field. The move by Microsoft away Newtonsoft JSON Library for .NET  Core 3+ has left me not knowing how to perform the equivalent method show below:

Example below used to work in Core 2.2 but now throws an error 'System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.'

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetSelectAllReportTemplatesAsync()
    {
        // Get the currently logged in user.
        var currentlyLoggedInUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

        // Note - ApplicationUserId is a foreign key field in the DB Table...
        var reportTemplates = _context.ReportTemplate
            .Where(s => s.Private == true & s.ApplicationUserId == currentlyLoggedInUser.Id)
            .OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToListAsync();

        return new JsonResult(reportTemplates);
    }
```

Ajax Call below:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Reports/ListView?handler=SelectAllReportTemplates",
            contentType: "json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                data.forEach(function (element) {
                    $("#editReportTemplateSelect").append('<option value="' + element.id + '">' + element.name + '</option>');
                    reportTemplatesArray.push({ id: '' + element.id + '', name: '' + element.name + '', description: '' + element.description + '', timePeriod: '' + element.timePeriod + '', startDate: '' + element.startDate + '', startTimeHours: '' + element.startTimeHours + '', startTimeMinutes: '' + element.startTimeMinutes + '', endDate: '' + element.endDate + '', endTimeHours: '' + element.endTimeHours + '', endTimeMinutes: '' + element.endTimeMinutes + '', logLevel: '' + element.logLevel + '', eventCategory: '' + element.eventCategory + '', eventType: '' + element.eventType + '', eventSource: '' + element.eventSource + '', userAccount: '' + element.userAccount + '', private: '' + element.private + '', });
                });
                $("#reportTemplateNameInput").val(''); // Clear the department name input field.
                $('#reportTemplateDescriptionTextarea').val(''); // Clear the department description textarea.
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#editreportTemplateSelectMessageBar").html("Error while making Ajax call!");
                setTimeout(function () { $("#editreportTemplateSelectMessageBar").html(''); }, 5000);
            }
        });
```

I tried marking the foreign key field in the model class with attribute '[JsonIgnore]' as i actually don't need to read nested properties from other tables, all i need is the ApplicationUserId string value itself. The only reason I have the tables using a relationship is for cascade delete.

I cant find any code examples which explains how to use the newer system?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I got my wires crossed a little here, after installing the former JSON functionality (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson patch) as a NuGet back into the project, i was still getting an object cycle error.

My solution was to set the foreign key field in the model class with the attribute [JsonIgnore], I then updated the OnGet method as below. The method now uses a more simplified LINQ query which passed without errors, I then do the filtering from the selection manually afterwords, creating a list that could then be returned back to the Ajax GET function.

Model Class:

```
public class ReportTemplate
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Primary Key

    other parameter object here...

    [Required]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Razor Page Model:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetSelectAllReportTemplates()
    {
        // Get the currently logged in user.
        var currentlyLoggedInUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

        // Create a List
        List<ReportTemplate> reportTemplates = new List<ReportTemplate>();

        // Run a simple get all LINQ query
        var reports = _context.ReportTemplate.OrderBy(s => s.Name);

        // Do the filtering, manually from the query collection 
        foreach (var report in reports)
        {
            if (report.Private == false)
            {
                reportTemplates.Add(report);
            }
            if (report.Private == true & report.ApplicationUserId == currentlyLoggedInUser.Id)
            {
                reportTemplates.Add(report);
            }
        }

        return new JsonResult(reportTemplates);
    }
```